# Why is the search functionality not working in my javascript code?

Tags: javascript, search, axios, fetch

"I've encountered an issue with the search functionality in my code. When I type in the search input, the results don't seem to update correctly. Could you please help me understand what might be causing this problem

```
let productContainer = document.querySelector('.product-container')
let arr_1 = [];
let arr_2 = [];
let search = document.querySelector('#search')
function getDataJson() {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/services`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            arr_2 = data;
            productContainer.innerHTML = "";
            arr_1 = arr_1.length || search.value ? arr_1 : data;
            arr_1.forEach(element => {
                productContainer.innerHTML += `
            <div class="product-image"><img src="${element.images}" alt=""></div>
            <h2>${element.title}</h2>
      
            `
            });
        })
}
getDataJson()
search.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    arr_1 = arr_2;
    arr_1 = arr_1.filter((el) => {
        return el.title.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase())
    });
    getDataJson();
})
```

I'm having trouble with the search feature in my JavaScript code. It doesn't seem to be working as expected when I input a search term. Can you guide me on how to troubleshoot and fix this issue

Comment: I'm very confused by the way you switch between `arr_1` and `arr_2`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not doing server-side filtering remove `getDataJson();` from the eventlistner.
When you update the `arr_1` array based on the search input, you are immediately calling the `getDataJson()` function, which fetches the data again and overwrites `arr_1` with the original data.

```
let productContainer = document.querySelector('.product-container');
let arr_1 = [];
let arr_2 = [];
let search = document.querySelector('#search');

function getDataJson() {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/services`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            arr_2 = data;
            productContainer.innerHTML = "";
            arr_1 = arr_1.length || search.value ? arr_1 : data;
            arr_1.forEach(element => {
                productContainer.innerHTML += `
                    <div class="product-image"><img src="${element.images}" alt=""></div>
                    <h2>${element.title}</h2>
                `;
            });
        });
}

getDataJson();

search.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    arr_1 = arr_2.filter((el) => {
        return el.title.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase());
    });
    productContainer.innerHTML = ""; // Clear the container before rendering new results
    arr_1.forEach(element => {
        productContainer.innerHTML += `
            <div class="product-image"><img src="${element.images}" alt=""></div>
            <h2>${element.title}</h2>
        `;
    });
});
```